# Band scale axis and static values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My visual has a `scaleBand` for the y axis. I have a data set that has categories, but these categories are not at the observational level, so for instance if appending circles I couldn't just do: `.attr('cy', function(d) {return yScale(???)})` The `???` denoting that there is nothing in my data at the observational level to split on. Instead, I need to split at the data label level, if that's the proper name for it. Here is the relevant section of code:

```js
var margins = {top:20, left:100, bottom:20, right:20};

var width = 800;
var height = 500;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([height,0])
    .padding(.1)
    .paddingInner(.2);

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#003366","#366092","#4f81b9","#95b3d7","#b8cce4","#f6d18b","#e4a733","#a6a6a6","#d9d9d9","#ffffcc","#b29866"]);

  var data = [
   {'fmc':'GF', 'aum':66.88, 'aumxmmf':27.62},
   {'fmc':'Ping An', 'aum':41.8, 'aumxmmf':10.76},
   {'fmc':'Southern', 'aum':80.25, 'aumxmmf':27.47}
];

var xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) {return d.aum});
var xMax = d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.aum});

var fundTypes = ['aum', 'aumxmmf'];

xScale.domain([xMin, xMax]);
yScale.domain(fundTypes);

graphGroup.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+0+","+height+")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
    .selectAll('text');

graphGroup.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(d3.axisRight(yScale))
    .selectAll('text')
    .attr("transform", "translate(-40,0)");

var aumCircles = graphGroup.selectAll('.aumCirc')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('circle')
.attr('class','aumCirc')
.attr('cx', function(d) {return xScale(d.aum)})
.attr('cy', yScale('aum'))
.attr('r', 4)
.style('fill', function(d) {return colorScale(d.fmc)});

var aumxmmfCircles = graphGroup.selectAll('.aumxmmfCirc')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('circle')
.attr('class', 'aumxmmfCirc')
.attr('cx', function(d) {return xScale(d.aumxmmf)})
.attr('cy', yScale('aumxmmf'))
.attr('r',4)
.style('fill', function(d) {return colorScale(d.fmc)});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

While no error is thrown, the result is not what I expected: the circles are appended in the middle of the two tick marks on the yAxis.

### Question

Why is this the default behavior for scaleBand? Shouldn't calling the axis on a static value (like `'aum'` still result in being in line with the tick marks? I don't understand why I call the axis the tick marks are in one place but when I call the axis again the circles are in a totally different place.

- I concluded the issue isn't because of the wrong `g` group through troubleshooting
- While I could use trial and error with `.paddingInner` and other padding settings, but I don't think that would be a good long terms solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have two questions here: one regarding how to use the data structure you have and another one regarding the scale. Because asking different, non-related issues in the same question is frowned upon here at S.O., I'll answer just the scale question:

You're using the wrong scale for the task, since a band scale has an associated bandwidth. Use a point scale instead:

```
var yScale = d3.scalePoint()
    //etc...
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var margins = {top:20, left:100, bottom:20, right:20};

var width = 800;
var height = 500;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scalePoint()
    .rangeRound([height,0])
    .padding(.2);

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#003366","#366092","#4f81b9","#95b3d7","#b8cce4","#f6d18b","#e4a733","#a6a6a6","#d9d9d9","#ffffcc","#b29866"]);

  var data = [
   {'fmc':'GF', 'aum':66.88, 'aumxmmf':27.62},
   {'fmc':'Ping An', 'aum':41.8, 'aumxmmf':10.76},
   {'fmc':'Southern', 'aum':80.25, 'aumxmmf':27.47}
];

var xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) {return d.aum});
var xMax = d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.aum});

var fundTypes = ['aum', 'aumxmmf'];

xScale.domain([xMin, xMax]);
yScale.domain(fundTypes);

graphGroup.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+0+","+height+")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
    .selectAll('text');

graphGroup.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(d3.axisRight(yScale))
    .selectAll('text')
    .attr("transform", "translate(-40,0)");

var aumCircles = graphGroup.selectAll('.aumCirc')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('circle')
.attr('class','aumCirc')
.attr('cx', function(d) {return xScale(d.aum)})
.attr('cy', yScale('aum'))
.attr('r', 4)
.style('fill', function(d) {return colorScale(d.fmc)});

var aumxmmfCircles = graphGroup.selectAll('.aumxmmfCirc')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('circle')
.attr('class', 'aumxmmfCirc')
.attr('cx', function(d) {return xScale(d.aumxmmf)})
.attr('cy', yScale('aumxmmf'))
.attr('r',4)
.style('fill', function(d) {return colorScale(d.fmc)});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```